# Add a script tag to div element and load code

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Ok here´s the problem i got. I found 100s of similar threads, but none of them covers the problem.

I got a  `< div id="ad_space_id">< /div>`  element.
What i want to do is to add a script tag to that div. What i did is:

```
src = https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adj/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=?

var adScript = document.createElement('script');
adScript.type = 'text/javascript';
adScript.setAttribute('src', src);
document.getElementById(adDivId).appendChild(adScript);
```

This all should be done dynamically i.e. after the page is loaded. The src i get from an XMLHttpRequest.

When I look at the html output, everything looks fine:

```
<div id="ad_space_1"><script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adj/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord= [timestamp];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=?"></script>

</div>)
```

My problem is, that the code doesn´t execute. 
(if i paste that code into an html file and load it in the browser it works fine).

can anybody help here please?!?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn´t execute since the script tag is inside the  element

You need to learn more about how the DOM(Document Object Model) loads and how javascript is loaded

Your Div is not ready yet when you try to execute the javascript.

You should watch video 6 and 7 in this tutorial, it explains a lot of both javascript loading and the importance of where you put your script code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeOSQcmLAtw&index=6&list=PL6n9fhu94yhUA99nOsJkKXBqokT3MBK0b

To ensure that the div is loaded in the DOM, you need to put it before(above) in Html, script functions should be place just before the closing body tag so that the DOM is ready for your script code to interact with it

```
<div id="ad_space_id"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // function call to do something with the div
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, will definitely check on that. But that brings me to another, more general question. what I try to do is to display a Rich Media Advertising (which is loaded by the script presented above) - just paste the div tag with the script above into an html page to see what it displays. I thought this would be quite standard and that there would be a standard way to achieve this. Am I missing something something? Is there another way to achieve that?

Comment: Inside the <Div> tag, you are not executing anything, you are just loading it to your page from an external source. put that <script> tag in the end of the body, just before the closing </Body> tag, that ensures that your entire DOM has loaded before you load the script and also the script function in the end of the document. But probably need more information to entirely understand what your goal is

Comment: My suggestion is still to watch the two videos i linked, they are quite short, like 10-15 minutes each, and afterwards you will understand quite well how DOM and JS interacts with eachother